# List view and array adapter not working? All data is displayed in one row of list

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android and I am trying to create a list view using an array adapter, a run method and multi threading. The list displays all the data from an array list as a single row.

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private Spinner mSpinnerAPI;
    private Button mButtonSubmit;
    private ProgressBar mProgressRequest;
    private ListView mEditTextResponse;
..
    ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData;

    ArrayList<SummaryData> summary;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSpinnerAPI = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAPI);
        mButtonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
        mEditTextResponse = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.editResponse);
        mProgressRequest = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressRequest);

        mButtonSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

  ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        toggleProgress(true);
        switch (mSpinnerAPI.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
            case 0: // Authenticate
              ...
            case 4: // Get Summary Day
                MovesAPI.getSummary_SingleDay(summaryHandler, "20150418", null);//Date changed to "20150117"
                break;
          ...
            case 10: // Get Storyline Day
                MovesAPI.getStoryline_SingleDay(storylineHandler, "20150418", "20140714T073812Z", false);//Date changed to "20150418" "null changed to"20140714T073812Z"
                break;
          ...
                toggleProgress(false);
                break;
        }

    }

   ...

    private MovesHandler<ArrayList<SummaryListData>> summaryHandler = new MovesHandler<ArrayList<SummaryListData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<SummaryListData> result) {
            toggleProgress(false);
            updateResponse("Summary Items : " + result.get(0)
                              + "Something: " + result.toString()
                           // + result.add(result.getSummaries().toString())
                            + "Something: " + result.toString()
            );
        }

     ...

    private MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> storylineHandler = new MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<StorylineData> result) {
            toggleProgress(false);
                 updateResponse(
                           "Date:\t" + result.get(0).getDate() + "\n"
                           + "-----------Activity 1 Summary--------\t" + "\n"
                           + "Activity:\t" + result.get(0).getActivity().toString() + "\n"//returns 1587 with .getCaloriesIdle()
                      ...
                           + "-----------Activity 2 Summary---------\t" + "\n"
                           + "Activity:\t" + result.get(0).getSummary().get(0).getActivity() + "\n"//returns 1587 with .getCaloriesIdle()
 ...


 + "-----------Segments---------\t" + "\n"
                           + "Type:\t" + result.get(0).getSegments().get(0).getType() + "\n"//returns 1587 with .getCaloriesIdle()

...
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(MovesStatus status, String message) {
            toggleProgress(false);
            updateResponse("Request Failed! \n"
                    + "Status Code : " + status + "\n"
                    + "Status Message : " + message + "\n\n"
                    + "Specific Message : " + status.getStatusMessage());
        }
    };

    public void toggleProgress(final boolean isProgrressing) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mProgressRequest.setVisibility(isProgrressing ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                mButtonSubmit.setVisibility(isProgrressing ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateResponse(final String message) {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                mButtonSubmit.setText(message);

                StorylineAdapter adapter = new StorylineAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_storyline, storylineData);
                mEditTextResponse.setAdapter(adapter);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

My ArrayAdapter class looks like this:

```
public class StorylineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SummaryData>{
    private Context context;
    private Runnable runnable;
private ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData;

public StorylineAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SummaryData> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.runnable = runnable;
    this.summary = objects;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_storyline, parent, false);


//Display in the TextView widget
SummaryData summary1 = summary.get(position);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText(summary1.getActivity());

return view;
}
}
```

Here is my parser class:

```
public class StorylineData extends ArrayList<StorylineData> {

...Getters/Setters...

/** ******************* Parser methods    

/**
 * Parse a {@link org.json.JSONObject} from storyline {@link org.json.JSONArray}, then return the corresponding {@link StorylineData} object.
 *
 * @param jsonObject : the storyline JSON object received from server
 * @return corresponding {@link StorylineData}
 */
public static StorylineData parse(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
    if (jsonObject != null) {

        StorylineData storylineData = new StorylineData();


        storylineData.date = jsonObject.optString("date");
        storylineData.caloriesIdle = jsonObject.optInt("caloriesIdle");
        storylineData.lastUpdate = jsonObject.optString("lastUpdate");
        storylineData.summary = new ArrayList<SummaryData>();
        storylineData.segments = new ArrayList<SegmentData>();



        /**Get the data associated with the array named summary **To get a specific JSONArray: Summary*/
        JSONArray summariesJsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("summary");

        if (summariesJsonArray != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < summariesJsonArray.length(); i++) {


            /**each time through array will need to get a reference of current object*/
            JSONObject summaryJsonObject = summariesJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);//declare instance of class object ob //array object called getJSONObject //passin indexvalu of (i)

                    if (summaryJsonObject != null) {
                    /**===============Translate data from json to Java=================*/
                        /**Create a new OBJECT OF ARRAY STORYLINE/SUMMARY*/
                        ArrayList<SummaryData> summary = new ArrayList<SummaryData>(); // initialisation must be outside the loop
                        storylineData.setSummary(summary);

                        /**Get summary from json into java*/
                        summariesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("distance");

                        /**Get date from json into java*/
                        String date = summaryJsonObject.optString("date");
                        storylineData.setDate(date);

                        /**Get group from json into java*/
                        String group = summaryJsonObject.optString("group");//Get name using key e.g. date
                        storylineData.setGroup(group);

               ...


                        storylineData.summary.add(SummaryData.parse(summaryJsonObject));
                        Log.d("StorylineDataCls \t sJo", summaryJsonObject.toString() + "Log\n");
                        System.out.println("print distance" + summariesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("distance"));
                        System.out.println("print summary" + summaryJsonObject);


                }
            }

        JSONArray segmentsJsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("segments");
        if (segmentsJsonArray != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < segmentsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject segment = segmentsJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

                if (segment != null) {

                    ArrayList<SegmentData> segments = new ArrayList<SegmentData>(); // initialisation must be outside the loop
                    storylineData.setSegments(segments);

                    String type = segment.optString("type");
                    storylineData.setType(type);

                  ...

                    storylineData.segments.add(SegmentData.parse(segment));


                    Log.d("StorylineDataCls \t sSo", segment.toString());

                }
            }
        }
        return storylineData;
    }
    return null;


}


}
```

I'm wondering if the reason the items are appearing in a single row may be because of a problem in the layout files?

```
Main Layout:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".StartScreen">

<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerAPI"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/API_Names"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Data"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerAPI"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressRequest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:id="@+id/editResponse"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#F8F8FF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
       />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editResponse"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editResponse"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSubmit"  />
```

```
Item Layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/flower_name_placeholder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Hi I have added a screenshot showing the problem. As you will see all my items appear in a single row. Thanks in advance for any suggestions you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. You should store and use in storylineData

```
public class StorylineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SummaryData>{
    private Context context;
private ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData;

    public StorylineAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SummaryData> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.storylineData = objects;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_storyline, parent, false);


    /*LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_storyline, parent, false);
    */

    //Display in the TextView widget
    SummaryData summary1 = storylineData.get(position);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(summary1.getActivity());

    return view;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gekkula, I have added that code as you advised but I have an error: identifier expected on the following line `StorylineData.StorylineAdapter adapter = new StorylineData.StorylineAdapter.(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_storyline, storylineData);`

Comment: I am confused, 'StorylineData.StorylineAdapter' why is the 'StorylineAdapter ' in 'StorylineData' ?

Comment: Sorry I am really new to android and I thought you were suggesting I put  'StorylineAdapter ' in 'StorylineData'. Please bare with me and explain in layman's terms where you suggest I place your code example.

Comment: Just run your previous code as it is. From your earlier results all the item should be displayed in a row. Now change the StorylineAdapter  class as i have posted above , check the results.

Comment: Thanks Gekkula. I have changed StorylineAdapter class as you posted and all the items still display in one row? Ill post my xml just in case the problem is in the xml?

Comment: in this line of the code i posted `tv.setText(summary1.getActivity());`  change it to `tv.setText(storylineData.size());`  If you see the text as 1 then your json parsing is error.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the following method in my MainActivity by adding an array adapter.

```
public void updateResponse(final String message) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                //MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

                    String[] stringArray = message.split("\n");

                    // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
                    // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
                    // array as a third parameter.
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray);
                    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
```